# Stratified sampling of a DataFrame into N splits without replacement

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn

Given I have a dataframe X, I want to split it into N dataframes such that the distribution of each set is roughly the same (i.e stratified)

Whats the best way of doing this?

Comment: A good post on stratified sampling in python is offered by @flaviobossolan in https://www.kaggle.com/flaviobossolan/stratified-sampling-python

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using the `StratifiedKFold` from `scikit-learn` using one of the columns from `X` as the one to be stratified by.